# Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.2 install script

Tags: node.js, node-modules, bcrypt

I am installing bcrypt for my project to use salting in hash function using the command -
`npm i bcrypt@3.0.2`

My current node version is 10.16.0
I have installed nvm to update my previous node version from 10.15.3

but while installing I am getting these errors-

```
"node" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.2 install: "node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.2 install script
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm, There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log og this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:Users\Ansh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-17T06_05_15-252Z-debug.log
```

**Update**
I have managed to install the bcrypt package but the issue mentioned is still present. Actually, I am using windows OS and for running these commands I was using Hyper as terminal, which is creating these errors. I tried to run the bcrypt install command using Administrative privileges through PowerShell and it was successful, without any errors.

I tried to install a few more packages(like passport, express-session, etc) through Hyper and I am facing somewhat similar errors, but when I run those in PowerShell, it works just fine.

I have managed to make things work for me, but I still don't understand the logic behind this. If anyone has any idea about it, please share and then I can close this.

Comment: Have you had a look at the complete log? And what about using the most recent version of `bcrypt`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bug reports at the [official repository](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+ELIFECYCLE) about this - have you made sure that you've read the full [installation instructions](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions) for this library, including the installation of some build tools? Maybe running the following line in a command line with admin privileges already helps?

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: Yes I have gone through all of them and even tried your mentioned command but it also shows a similar error, I think the main error is this - `npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm, There is likely additional logging output above`

Comment: And what about inspecting the complete log file for this? Maybe it lists more information

Comment: I checked that too, I couldn't make much out of it, ```
1222 verbose stack at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
1222 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
1222 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ansh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
1222 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
1222 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
1222 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this command line maybe its will help you

> npm install bcrypt@3 --save